# Identify process sending (emulated) key strokes

Tags: windows-10, process

After startup my machine has a lot of IO activity and if I open the start menu right after logging in, random sequences of `s` and `.` seem to be (emulated) key strokes <strike>sent to stdout</strike> showing up in the search field like in this screenshot:

[image]

How can I identify the source process?

- I already ran a virus check on my drive from a safe boot media but nothing was found.
- I'm only able to reproduce this after a cold boot, not a reboot.
- I'm also not able to reproduce this booting in safe mode (minimal option).

Also I'm not able to catch chars by firing up notepad - the editor will simply loose focus there's no other trace.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of this output. If this appears as a window on the screen, you can identify the process by using [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and dragging the bull's-eye icon on top of it.

Comment: There's no output window (cmd or else) to capture. I only noticed this by chance because (unexpected ) characters are emitted to the standard output and did show up in the search textbox when I opened the Start Menu. I'll add a screenshot of this as soon as I'm back home.

Comment: Let me know when you do. Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.

Comment: @harrymc Added a screenshot of just as it happened when I logged in and pressed the Win key. After 1 or 2 sec the character `s` appeared in the search box.

Comment: If there is no output windows then it is not an output to stdout. The screen shot looks more like emulated key strokes. You can trace them using a Tools like spy++ (spyxx.exe by Microsoft).

Comment: Amazing. This might be caused by some installed software. To check, [Start Windows 10 in Safe Mode](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2304-boot-into-safe-mode-windows-10-a.html) and check if the problem arrives with only Windows software in play.

Comment: As @Robert mentions, what you are referring to certainly isn't STDOUT.  A process doesn't just 'spew' STDOUT to to topmost window as keystrokes.  This is more like something (poorly) using 'sendkeys' to a topmost window.  WOW!  I like figuring out who is running garbage software on my box!

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas What's odd is, is that it doesn't like Notepad++ or Windows Terminal - tried those but they just loose focus and key strokes go (presumably) to nirvana.

Comment: Have you disabled EVERYTHING from your startup?  Have you thought of running a key logger?  It might give you a better clue as to what is going on.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas As harrymc suggested I'll give spy++ a try. Since booting in safe mode made it go away I'll have to start disabling selectively to find the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As booting in Safe Mode fixed the problem, this indicates
that some third-party application is responsible for it.

To locate the problematic application, you may use the free tool
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

This utility shows all programs configured to run during system bootup or login
in its "Everything" tab.
You may turn off startup items with a click and return
them later with another click. You may avoid listing Microsoft products by
using the menu *Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*,
*Hide Empty Locations* and *Hide Windows Entries*

I would suggest turning off startup entries in bunches, drilling down to the startup
program that causes this behavior. Once identified, it might have some setting
that can avoid the problem, or can be left out of startup and only be invoked
when required (verify that once invoked it does not add another startup
entry, but such can again be disabled by Autoruns).

Comment: After 8 or 9 reboots with narrowing down the startup entries using Autoruns, I managed to identify the culprit: Logitech LCD Manager (lcdmon.exe), an app that came with my game panel which allows you to forward notifications (mail etc.) to the game panel LCD display. I'd happily honor your answer with a 500 bounty but all my rep is over at [so] and I'd like to keep my commenting privilege here.