# How to mute windows beep sound in SSMS 18.5 everytime you tab in the table designer?

Tags: windows-10, ssms, ms-sql

**FOUND THE ISSUE:** Seems it's not a known bug and I've reported it on their [Uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/40318435--confirmed-bug-ssms-18-2-ok-18-3-1-bug). This seems to happen only on SSMS 18.3.1 onwards up to SSMS 18.5. On SSMS 18.2 and lower the issue does not happen. Thanks everyone!

---

Original text:

Each time I use the table designer and the focus changes from any field (Column Name, Data Type, Allow Nulls, etc.) either by pressing the Tab key or switching to another window, the classic windows beep sound plays. And it's annoying as heck, whoever decided it was a good idea should revisit his objective in life.

SSMS (SQL Management Studio) doesn't even appear in the volume mixer, so I can't even mute it from there unless I mute the entire output device (or System sounds) which isn't what I want. Is anybody else experiencing this or is it happening only on my computer?

Typing "beep" in the SSMS preferences doesn't help much either...

[image]

**EDIT:** Thanks for the Autoruns and Windows Sounds suggestion. Unfortunately, even though I disabled all items in there, and SSMS does not show any sound to be played in the Windows Sounds panel, the beep is still there! :(

Comment: In Options, if you enter "beep" in the search field, do you see a useful option?

Comment: Oh sorry, thanks @harrymc. Unfortunately, it doesn't show anything. I've updated the OP

Comment: Strange. One "beep" I know of is in *Options > Query Results* and is called "Play the Windows default beep when a query batch completes". I don't have SSMS installed here to check it out.

Comment: Yeah, I know that beep too and I disabled it but it did have no effect :(

Comment: Does this beep happen if you boot in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc interestingly, it doesn't. I have audio in safe mode, but the beep isn't happening there :/

Comment: Go to Settings >System > Sound > Scroll down and select Sound Control Panel > Select Sounds tab from above, Windows Default Sound Scheme would be selected there, now scroll to the bottom and see if you find SSMS listed there with all the conditions as nodes for which it plays default windows sound as Windows lists major softwares there like it has listed Corel Photo-paint and VS in mine. It it's there, change sound to none as displayed [here](https://imgur.com/a/SDesTHC).

Comment: Also, the list there is sorted alphabetically.

Comment: I think this means that the sound is caused by some installed product, not by SSMS. Try [this advice](https://superuser.com/a/1531922/8672).

Comment: Or you could try to repair or even reinstall SSMS.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, unfortunately even though I disabled all items in there, and SSMS does not show any sound to be played in the Windows Sounds panel, the beep is still there! I've even reinstalled SSMS with reboots and all. No dice :/

Comment: Nevermind @harrymc thanks for your help, it turns out it's an issue on their end. Seems it's not a known bug and I've reported it on their Uservoice. This seems to happen only on SSMS 18.3.1 onwards up to SSMS 18.5. On SSMS 18.2 and lower the issue does not happen. Thanks anyways!

Comment: It's the current Exclamation sound that chimes on query window close which is mighty annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to repair or even reinstall SSMS, but if it doesn't help,
the fact that booting in Safe Mode fixes the problem might indicate that some
third-party application is responsible for it.

In this case, see the following post for finding out a troublesome product
[Identify process sending (emulated) key strokes](https://superuser.com/questions/1529270/identify-process-sending-emulated-key-strokes).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately even though I disabled all items in there, and SSMS does not show any sound to be played in the Windows Sounds panel, the beep is still there! I've even reinstalled SSMS with reboots and all. No dice :/

Comment: It's then something that Autoruns can't disable, but I don't know of a better tool.

Comment: No problem, the Autoruns app was helpful and didn't know it worked on Win10 so I'm awarding the bounty for staying with me along the way. It turns out it's an issue on their end. Seems it's not a known bug and I've reported it on their Uservoice. This seems to happen only on SSMS 18.3.1 onwards up to SSMS 18.5. On SSMS 18.2 and lower the issue does not happen. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

I've add this exact problem before when filling out grades in an online spreadsheet. Assuming that it isn't caused by another program and is the result of windows itself, you might be able to globally disable that sound effect in Windows.

Go to Settings->Personalization->Themes (Left side menu)->Sounds

[Sounds Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CxWQ.png)

Every system sound will be in that list. I'm not sure exactly which sound it is without hearing it, but disabling that specific sound effect might stop the annoying beep. Try going through the list and see if you can find it, there might a couple with same sound.

As far as I'm aware, there isn't a way to disable the sound effects for specific programs. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that disables the sound overall for the entire OS which is what I'm not looking for. I guess it could work as a temporary solution, but I recall this didn't happen in versions before 18.x

Answer (score -2):

Go to Settings->Personalization->Themes (Left side menu)->Sounds

Default Beed Set to none

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but this does not address the problem where the need is to mute the beep sound in just SSMS. This does it for the whole OS, which is not what I'm looking for. Plus, if you take the time to read the comments/answers above, the issue was on Microsoft side with that specific SSMS release. Subsequent ones didn't suffer from this, and the bug was fixed :) not to mention your answer is an exact duplicate of Freebird's, and this question was already answered.