# Thinkpad L560 - Screen Turns on and off every few seconds, temporarily fixed by driver uninstall

Tags: windows, laptop, drivers, thinkpad

A colleague of mine has a ThinkPad L560 with an i5 6200U and 16 GB of RAM. Recently, he encountered a problem with it: As soon as the Laptop boots into Windows (not on the BIOS screen!) the monitor turns off, stays dark for a few second, turns on, turns off again etc., rendering the computer totally useless.

As a troubleshoot, I first tried to boot into Windows Safe Mode (The Laptop still ran Win7). In safe mode, everything worked as expected. I therefore thought that it must be a software issue. Since the machine needed an Update anyways, I made a clean install of Windows 10. 
First, it seemed as if the problem was fixed, I connected it to the Internet and installed some standard software. 
A few minutes later however, to my utter surprise, the computer made the "device disconnected" sound and the problem occured again. Whenever the computer booted up, it instantly stopped working correctly.

I then tried to boot into safe mode again, which, again, worked properly. At this point, I was unsure wether it was a software or a hardware error. To verify, I used the Display Driver Uninstaller Tool by DriverGuru to remove all display drivers. After that, the laptop booted normally again. The problem reoccured a few minutes later, though. I figured that it might have something to do with the automatic driver installation by Windows Update, so I went under Control Panel -> System and Security -> RAM and CPU Speed -> Advanced System Options -> Hardware -> Device installation settings and disabled the automatic device installation altogether. Unfortunately, that changed nothing and the problem persisted after uninstalling all drivers and rebooting the computer again. 
When I stop the machine from connecting to the internet, however, the problem does **not** reoccur, which makes me think that it must have something to do with stuff being downloaded. If I run Ubuntu from a live disk, the computer works as expected.

I really have no idea what to try with this machine anymore. Has anyone ever encountered a similar issue? Is it a hardware issue? Is there something I can install manually?

Comment: Try the latest drivers [from Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/88355/graphics-drivers/graphics-for-6th-generation-intel-processors/intel-hd-graphics-520.html), and reboot.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, tried it out, did nothing, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Some advice:

- Run `chkdsk`
- Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) and DISM (as explained in the link)
- Search the Event Viewer for more info
- Run deep antivirus scans by a couple of reputable antivirus products.
  If the computer is unusable in the normal mode, try booting in Safe Mode with Network.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, I'll try it tomorrow. However, I highly doubt that it has something to do with the filesystem or malware, as I've already tried to swap the disk and make a completely clean Windows installation. Safe Mode with Network does actually work, but unfortunately not via wireless.

Comment: This might then relate to some installed product. Did this also happen when Windows was in vanilla state? If it did not, then try [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1531922/8672).

Comment: It did, unfortunately, also happen with a 100% clean and fresh Windows installation without any additional software.

Comment: Have you thought about a hardware error that is only encountered in Windows?

Comment: You're right. That's sadly the most probable explanation. I already tried opening up the machine to check wether there were any loose connections or obvious damage to the PCB's and capacitors, but I found nothing. I'm no Louis Rossman, unfortunately.

Comment: Running [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for as long as possible tests RAM, but also indirectly CPU & memory controller.